# XMLHTTPRequest not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The following code I am using to update a textarea dynamically without reloading the entire page.

It was working last night but stopped working when I tried using it this morning. The `alert(request.readyState+" "+request.status)` returns `2 0` and `4 0`... help?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
      var url="http://www.suchandsuch.net/ChatBowl/text.txt";
      var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET",url,true); 


     request.onreadystatechange= function(){
    //alert(request.readyState+" "+request.status); 
    if (request.readyState ==4 && request.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML=request.responseText;
    }  
  };
    request.send(null);
 }  
var int=self.setInterval('init()', 3000);
</script>
```

I sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: are you accessing the page with file:/// protocol? are you trying the page under the same domain www.suchandsuch.com?

Comment: tried both Opera and FireFox... I can try the others real quick to see if they work.. Not using IE so the ActiveXObject thing shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: if status is 0, it often indicates that the request don't go through at all, timeout or refused. It should not trigger the different readyStates, but I know that Firefox at least tend to show these requests in Firebug as status 0.

Comment: And please: `self.setInterval(init, 3000)`, not `self.setInterval('init()', 3000)`

Comment: yea I'm accessing the file at the same domain name. I get the same results in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Aparrantley it didn't like the URL... when I changed it started working a little better... I might be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a URL issue. The logic is sound though.